# SQL query to create a nested pydantic structure

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

While working with SQLAlchemy 2.x and FastAPI, I ran into the problem of creating a nested structure for pydantic serialization.

The specific essence of the problem lies in the implementation of the sql query. The fact is that the received data comes as a single tuple and pydantic does not see a nested structure in it.

i.e. i want to get following response json structure using many to one relationship

```json
{
  "id": 0,
  "username": "string",
  "avatar_url": "string",
  "create_at": "2023-03-30T10:56:03.625Z",
  "is_active": true,
  "user_role": {
    "name": "string",
    "color": "string"
  }
}
```

how to change the database query code to get this?

**Parts of my code:**

crud.py

```py
# this code does not work correctly for the implementation of the current task
async def get_current_user(user_id: int, session: AsyncSession):
    result = await session.execute(
        select(
            Users.id, Users.username, Users.avatar_url, Users.create_at, Users.is_active,
            UsersRole.name, UsersRole.color
        )
        .join(Users)
        .where(Users.id == user_id)
    )
    return result.first()
```

models.py

```py
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, nullable=False)
    password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    avatar_url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    create_at: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(default=datetime.utcnow())
    is_active: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=True)

    role_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users_role.id"), nullable=False)
    role: Mapped["UsersRole"] = relationship()


class UsersRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_role"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    color: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(7), nullable=False)
```

schemas.py

```py
class ResponseRoleUser(BaseModel):
    name: str
    color: str


class ResponseCurrentUser(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    avatar_url: str | None
    create_at: datetime
    is_active: bool
    role: ResponseRoleUser

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

endpoint.py

```py
@router.get("/me", response_model=ResponseCurrentUser)
async def current_data_user(
    ...
    session: Annotated[AsyncSession, Depends(get_async_session)]
):
    # for example
    user = await get_current_user(id, session)
    return user
```

Tried experimenting with relationship() but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By listing all the database columns individually, SQLAlchemy will return a [`Row` object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) instead of a `Users` instance, which won't map cleanly to your Pydantic models. If you instead rewrite to query the ORM classes directly:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

async def get_current_user(user_id: int, session: AsyncSession):
    result = await session.execute(
        select(Users)
        .where(Users.id == user_id)
        .options(joinedload(Users.role))
    )
    return result.first()
```

Note that using `joinedload` tells SQLAlchemy to join in the `users_role` table and populate the `Users.role` relationship, rather than lazily loading it, which doesn't work when using async SQLAlchemy (since all IO operations need to be awaited).

Returning `Users` objects will allow pydantic's ORM mode to properly convert to `ResponseCurrentUser`.